# SignTool - sign $(TargetFileName) in VS solution in release configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2015, signtool

In Visual Studio 2015, I want to use SignTool to sign the dll, exe, and msi files of the solution on a successful build. That is, using a post-build event.
I have looked at this post: 
[Disable signing when in debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889640/in-visual-studio-can-i-disable-signing-my-application-when-in-debug/890049#890049) and it has been useful.
So I have this in the post-build event:

> call "$(ProjectDir)$(ConfigurationName)_sign.bat"

where the Debug_sign.bat is blank and the Release_sign.bat looks something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign 
/f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\mySPC.pfx" 
/t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll 
/v $(TargetFileName)
```

The problem with this of course is that $(TargetFileName) is not recognised.
It would however, really help if I didn't have to specify the file name of the exe/dll/msi or whatever for the particular project, and just use the TargetFileName.

So, how could I have two cases (release & debug) where only with the release configuration the files are signed, and only the TargetFileName is signed? 
Presently, I have SignTool's path hardcoded in the bat file. I would like to have as few as possible scripts to keep track of.

Comment: I suspect you can probably add an argument to your call line in the build event and then access that argument as %1 in the .bat file

Comment: I have just tried your suggestion, but I still get an error in VS. Think my syntax is wrong. Would you mind giving an example using the snippets I have given above?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I've got it to work! :-)